# CoreData count for to-many relationships of all children

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an table/entity "Level" that is a "level" of a law.

Each instance of Level can have two relevant relationships:

- One or more sublevels (to-many relationship to same entity) and/or
- One or more Articles (to-many relationship to "Article" entity).

For each Level I want to show the number of Articles for that Level and all it's related sublevels in total.

I can do this by looping through the various levels in the sublevels set but I would using a fetched property instead be better?

I guess I need something like

`totalArticles = articles.count + sublevels.articles.count`

Or should I be storing the count for each sublevel as an attribute/fetched property and then using @sum on the parent level?

Can anyone help with how I might achieve this?